# Multiple SSL errors after upgrading to OS X 10.9.4 in Chrome and Safari

Tags: support, ssl

After I upgraded to OS X 10.9.4 I could no longer access Stackoverflow or Github and a number of other sites due to SSL errors.

This is happening on Chrome 36.0.1985.125 and Safari 7.0.5

In Firefox 30.0 I can access all sites.

- I have HTTPS Everywhere installed in all browsers.

  - I have attempted to disable the plugin but sites still fail.
- After trying the solution presented [at this website](http://jnystromdesign.se/2014/03/cannot-connect-to-the-real-github-com-ssl-error-after-mac-osx-10-9-2-update/), I had a new set of errors. **note**: the errors shown on that site were the original errors I was getting for github. I did not check stackoverflow until after deleting DigiCert
- Unable to access github via terminal now.
- Everything works normally on my linux machine.
- I tested the sites at different times of the day all with the same results.

## New errors which happened after deleting DigiCert files.

### Chrome

---

> ### The server's security certificate is not yet valid!
>
> You attempted to reach **stackoverflow.com** but the server presented
>   a certificate that is not yet valid. No information is available to
>   indicate whether that certificate can be trusted. Google Chrome cannot
>   reliably guarantee that you are communicating with
>   **stackoverflow.com** and not an attacker. Your computer's clock is currently set to Sunday, July 27, 2014 1:07:21 PM. Does that look
>   right? If not, you should correct your system's clock and then refresh
>   this page.
>
> You should not proceed, **especially** if you have never seen this
>   warning before for this site.

### Safari

---

**For Stackoverflow I get the following message:**

> This website does not supply identify information.
>
> The connection to this website is not fully secure because it contains
>   unencrypted elements (such as images).

**For Github I get the following message:**

> **Safari can't open the page**
>
> Safari can't open the page "https://github.com" because Safari can't
>   establish a secure connection to the server "github.com"

## Screenshots

---

[chrome / stackoverflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r20sy.png) (same results on github)

[safari / stackoverflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfKWv.png)

[safari / github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ib8h.png)

---

Please send help.

Comment: Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange are not supported under HTTPS. The team are working on it, but until they make an announcement you *must* assume that any access you have is temporary. As for Github, why is that a problem we need to know about?

Comment: This is probably a bug with **your system**. Stack Overflow currently uses a certificate that began on 7/1/2013 and expires on 7/6/2016. The fact that you also have problems with Github kind of reinforces that idea. As ChrisF mentions, though, just because Stack Overflow *has* a certificate doesn't mean it's fully supported yet. Not all elements on every page are served over a secure connection yet.

Comment: I find these comments confusing. I upgraded my OS and subsequently lost the ability to access Stackoverflow in either chrome or safari. I am being given ssl errors – if this is not a meta issue, should it be posted to main stackoverflow.com? Edit: I'm thinking this belongs in another section altogether Agreed that it relates to my system, but others are having similar issues as a quick google search shows. I'm hoping to get help solving the root issue.

Comment: @sandwichthecat no it shouldn't be posted on the main site. It's not a programming problem you're having. **If** SO supported HTTPS you're in the right place, but at the moment **it doesn't** so we can't help you with any problems you're having accessing the site via HTTPS.

Comment: @ChrisF Thanks – i think i got my sites confused. just as an fyi, disabling https everywhere fixed stackoverflow issues, github is still broken. will go through the proper channels to fix.. should i delete this question?

Comment: @sandwichthecat - you can't now it has an upvoted answer.

Comment: Check that your system date/time are correct. :)

Comment: @Qix - system date/time are correct.

Comment: Then it's definitely a bug in your system/browser.

Comment: @Qix thanks was suspecting the same. Will try a re-install of browser and then manual re-install of last upgrade.

Comment: Someone could be trying to MITM you.

Comment: I had this problem too. Note this is more than just Stack Overflow having this prob, for me it's any site with a DigiCert SSL certificate.

Comment: I Ended up reformatting my computer. I had a host of other problems. Obviously this fixed the issue, but I still don't understand what caused it in the first place. **Edit**: I understand it was related to SSL and Digicert issues, I don't understand what triggered these things. I was using HTTPSEverywhere for a very longtime prior to running into these issues along with Adblock. I disabled those plugins and nothing fixed the issue. Completely reinstalled chrome and nothing worked. The upgrade to 10.9.4 seems to have triggered the issue, but I can't be sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keychain Access ->  click on System Roots on the left, and then click on Certifcates on the bottom left.

Find the certified with problem, in my case was "DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA". Double-click on certificate, expand the section labled "trust".  Change the "Use System Default" to "Aways Trust".  Close window - you should be prompted for the password.

If you didn't re-enter your password upon closing the window, the setting didn't take.  The blue "+" should appear after a few seconds.

Test your browser... if every thing is ok try to go back to "Use System Default".

Comment: Is this safe, and what is causing the issue specifically?

Comment: My case is reverse: "Aways Trust" for "DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA" does not work, change to "Use System Default" fix it. Thanks for point out this cert anyway.

Answer (score 6):

Turn off HTTPS Everywhere, or at least disable it for Stack Overflow and all other Stack Exchange sites.

HTTPS is not officially supported yet. There are issues with the format of the URLS - particularly for meta and chat that mean they can't get a sensible number of certificates. I believe there are issues with accessing imgur as well (but I could be wrong about that).

Until these problem is resolved you should just use HTTP.

Comment: Accessing Imgur results in warnings about secure content. I believe Imgur supports HTTPS so it's a matter of detecting these URLs and providing the secure links vs. the unsecure links. However, that's a problem they're going to have to tackle as it could potentially add a lot of overhead.

Comment: @Qix - I think the issue is going through the database making sure any links are secure when they can be secure. It won't be a quick fix.

Comment: exactly. <length>

Comment: @ChrisF isn't that solved by using links without protocol added? As in <img src="//i.imgur.com/<foo>">  If so, even if the links are in the db I would assume they could be filtered prior to serving up content.

Comment: @sandwichthecat Each post is translated into HTML when the post is saved into the database. So on each page render, there is no server side rendering of the Markdown making the site very fast. It would be incredibly expensive to process the markdown/HTML for each post every page load. The best bet would be to have a job in the database reprocess all the HTML/Markdown using protocol relative URLs (or even https) as you mention.

Comment: @StevenV Nice – I didn't know the site's architecture.. agreed that a quick solution would be a script that parses all generated html and removes HTTP: and HTTPS:

Edit: that would be the solution for generated content, along with stripping out the protocol from future saves of course.

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete

```
/Library/Preferences/com.apple.security.*.plist
```

then reboot.

Comment: This doesn't sound as good advice. Any references that explain why this is a good idea and why this works?